# How to Change an Audio File So It'll Sound Sci-Fi

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, scifi

I am new to sound design and I don't even know where to start learning that.
However, I'm building a space shooter game and I need sound effects for it. I have already bought a package with sound effects that I can use, but the thing is that they sound very realistic and it doesn't fit to my game as it is a 2D game without any realistic visuals.

What I want to do is change the sound effects so they will sound more sci-fi or cartoon-ish. So how can I do that? Currently the sound editing software that I have is FL Studio, but if another software is needed please tell me about it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, that is a very general question, it sounds like you do have a lot to learn.  I can't really answer you question specifically without knowing what the sounds are and what they're meant to become, and to be honest if you've not got a basic understanding of sound design my answers would be lost on you.

First up, get onto youtube, go watch as many documentaries as you can about sound design, anything about Ben Burt, interviews with him etc.

Next, get reading about sound design in games, here's some great resources:

www.gameaudio101.com

http://designingsound.org/

www.soundesign.info

www.thesoundarchitect.co.uk/interviews/

Finally if all else fails search websites like freesound.org for the assets you need, contrary to popular belief amongst game audio professionals there are plenty of great sound recordists and designers contributing, you just need to sift through the chaff.

Best help I can give in the time available

Comment: You are right, I do have a LOT to learn but the thing is that I don't have time to learn this right now (nor the real passion to be honest). I am so new to this to the point that I can't even explain what I want, but I am pretty desprate. So I hoped that maybe I can just ask about making a sound become more sci-fi or game friendly and someone will be able to give me a name of a filter/software/effect(s) that does that... I see now, though, that it's much more complicated... But still, I'll check the resources you've provided, so again, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Bit-crushing is one way to make your "realistic" samples sound "retro". You should be able to find a free bitcrusher VST online. I am not familiar with FL Studio but it seems to only come with "Fruity Squeeze" which has mixed reviews online. So find a bitcrusher ("8-bit") effect and apply it to your samples.

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting with envelope filtering with a substantial amount of resonance on sound sources with prominent transients such as gun shots and other various weapons sound effects.

Frequency shifters are also a great tool for making things atonal and spacey. Take a look at Melda Production's Frequency Shifter as it's actually one of the better shifters out there since it doesn't alter the pitch of the source sound.